# IoC in EJB throws ClassNotFoundException and 'Failed to marshal EJB parameters'

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I have the following setup:

We are running an application on JBoss 6.4 where we have an ear deployed with EJBs containing the business logic. A war is deployed as well, where some webservices and websockets live.

Now I'd like to have something like this:

**on ear side**

```
@Remote
public interface EventConsumer extends Serializable {

    void onEventMessage(Topic topic, String message, String principalName);

    void onErrorMessage(Topic topic, Throwable t, String principalName);

}
```

and

```
public class EventLogImpl {

    private final List<EventConsumer> consumers;

    public EventLogImpl() {
        this.consumers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void registerEventConsumer(EventConsumer consumer) {
        consumers.add(consumer);
    }
    // other stuff...
}
```

this whole thing is exposed as EJB:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@Remote(EventLog.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class EventLogEJB implements EventLog {

    private final EventLogImpl delegate = new EventLogImpl();

    @Override
    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    public void registerEventConsumer(EventConsumer consumer) {
        delegate.registerEventConsumer(consumer);
    }

    // stuff

}
```

**on war side**

```
@ServerEndpoint("/ws/eventLog/")
@Stateless
public class EventLogWebsocket implements EventConsumer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final EventLog eventLogService;

    public EventLogWebsocket() {
        eventLogService = createEventLogService();
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        eventLogService.registerEventConsumer(this);
    }

    // other ws stuff

    @Override
    public void onEventMessage(Topic topic, String message, String principalName) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorMessage(Topic topic, Throwable t, String principalName) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    private EventLog createEventLogService() {
        EventLog logService = // some proxy stuff since its remote. works fine
        return logService;
    }

}
```

**the problem**

unfourtunately this doesn't work when the ws open method gets called:

```
ERROR [xyz.ws.EventLogWebsocket] (http-/0.0.0.0:8280-17) error occurred in websocket: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014154: Failed to marshal EJB Parameters
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xyz.ws.EventLogWebsocket from [Module "deployment.abc-app-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.abc-infrastructure-ejb-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
...
```

Debugging into the jboss ModuleClassLoader shows that the EJB fails to load the EventLogWebsocket class. But in this IoC setup that's what I want: not caring about the implementation of this specifc Interface...

Right now I don't see the solution... do you? :)

Comment: Is the  WAR in the EAR or separate from it?

Comment: the WAR is separate but running in the same jBoss

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that @Remote method invocations use RMI, so:

1. all method parameters and return values must be `java.io.Serializable`.
2. method parameters are passed by *value*, not reference, so the receiving method gets a copy of the object - not the actual object.

As you have seen, the initial call:

```
 eventLogService.registerEventConsumer(this);
```

has problems:

When the EJB side attempts to deserialise the `consumer` object it tries to recreate a copy of the `EventLogWebsocket`, but this class is not available in the EAR and it fails.

Furthermore the `EventLogWebsocket` parameter must be a serializable object. It claims to be serializable, but it's not because it contains that `EventLog` object which is not serializable.

Even if you rectify all these problems, it still won't work because the EJB has a *copy* of the `EventLogWebsocket` so it will not be sent any of the event notifications anyway.

Therefore, the first thing you need to do is get rid of the @Remote interface. This means you must include the WAR in the EAR and use @Local interfaces.

But you still need to be wary because classes in EAR/WAR files can see EAR/EJB classes but the converse is not true - EAR/EJB classes cannot sees classes in EAR/WAR files.

If you are still have classloading problems after repackaging then consider putting everything in the WAR file and lose the EAR altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems like I forget this whole copy thing way too often.

Would some message queue framework help in this case (HornetQ would potentially be available...)? Or would we be facing the same issues there as well? I mean, how do they handle this callback stuff?

Comment: If you need the separate deployments then you could use JMS for this - yes. You might also try something like Apache Kafka as used in this [scaleable coffee shop example](https://github.com/sdaschner/scalable-coffee-shop). However if you can get everything into the same class loader (single WAR deployment) then you can use CDI events and observers instead. You certainly want to avoid RMI if you can.